# VMWare split screen between host and guest

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, vmware-workstation

I am working on a Windows 10 machine. I have a copy of VMware Workstation 15 Pro. In VMWare, I will be running Ubuntu and do most of my development there. What I want to do is have one monitor that shows Windows and another that shows Ubuntu. I want the Ubuntu VM to by full screen in one of the monitors. Is this possible?

Apologies if the answer to this is simple. I am used to doing all of my development on a Mac. I started a new job recently that required the Windows/VMWare setup. I want to purchase 2 monitors for my home office but I want to make sure that the idea works before I make the purchase.

Comment: VMware is an application (for this purpose like Excel or Word). Drag the VMware app (the whole thing) to the other screen. Depending on your setup, it should work fine.

Comment: Oh, something important that I forgot to mention. I want the Ubuntu VM to by full screen in one of the monitors

Comment: You can view Full Screen within VMare - That works. Keep VMware as a self contained app (even using full screen) and it should work just fine. I use VMware myself.

Comment: I'd mae this the accepted answer if I could

Comment: I posted an answer for you

Comment: If you still have the Mac, you could always run Windows AND Ubuntu in VMWare [or Parallels], & still have the Mac running full-time too ;)

Comment: I can't use the Mac work work unfortunately. Everything is very locked down for this company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware works as an application and for this purpose, like Excel or Word.

So you can drag the complete VMware app to another monitor and that will work.

Within VMware, you can run a guest full screen as well . I run VMware myself and that works.

Good luck with your second monitor.